# Android Realm: Roll back transaction

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to figure out the order of operations with which I update a realm object remotely and locally. 
Basically it is:

a) Update the local realm object.
b) Save the object remotely.
c) Rollback the previous commit if there was an error.

```
User user = ... // Fetched from realm.
RealmList<FavoriteSong> realmList = new RealmList<>();
realmList.addAll(favoriteSongs); // The collection of favorite songs that has been selected.
user.setFavoriteSongs(realmList);
// At this point my local copy of User has been updated with favorite songs.

// Now I will update remotely.
mUserServices.updateUser(user, new UserServices.UserListener() {
    @Override
    public void done(Exception e) {
        if(e != null) {
            // Since there was a remote update failure, can I roll back the local copy to the previous state?
        }
    }
});
```

Is a rollback possible, and if not, what is the preferred strategy to handle this scenario with Realm?

Comment: `realm.cancelTransaction()` can cancel currently open transaction.

Comment: Technically transaction should be rolled back in remote system where failure happened.

Comment: @Saurabh - Since I would have received an error back from the server client-side, the transaction would never have occurred on the server.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Ok, cool that works, looks like if I use a realm.beginTransaction() instead of the Transaction callback I can control when and if the transaction is committed.

Comment: You can force the `executeTransactionAsync()` background operation to cancel instead of commit by throwing a `RuntimeException`. I think.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Ok gotcha, I'll give that a whirl as well.